# mock injected class in Akka actor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, akka, powermockito

I´m using PowerMock and I´ve seen that using `@InjectMock` I can get the injected class in my test.

But what I need is that using an Akka actor which has injected a class, run a test against that actor and inject a mock class in there.

```
class A extends Actor{

  @Inject private B b;//How can I mock this class?

}

@Test
public test(){
          final Props props = Props.create(A.class, new A());
        testActorRef = TestActorRef.create(actorSystem, props);
           Future<Object> ask = Patterns.ask(testActorRef);


}
```

Just to clarify the source code cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change to constructor injection:

```
class A extends Actor{
  private final B b;//How can I mock this class?
  A(@Inject  B b){
    this.b=b;
  }
}
```

which leads to this test:

```
@Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule(); 

@Mock private B mockedB;

@Test
public test(){
          // configure mockedB here
          A a = new A(mockedB);

          // do something with a
          // verify method invocations on b
}
```

Comment: I change the question, I´m afraid the source code cannot be modify